# Do split one class hierarchy into several or not?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, xml-serialization

For now, we have a .NET application that leans on the standard .NET XML serialization/deserialization mechanism. The example is simplified but the meaning is the same.

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public abstract void Draw();
    public abstract void Clear();
    public abstract void Scale(double scale);
}

[XmlType("Circle")]
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }

    public override void Draw() {}

    public override void Clear() {}

    public override void Scale(double scale) {}
}

[XmlType("Rectangle")]
public class Rectangle: Shape
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public override void Draw() {}

    public override void Clear() {}

    public override void Scale(double scale) {}
}

public class Picture
{
    public double Scale { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayAttribute("Shapes")]
    public Collection<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }

    public void Setup()
    {
        foreach (Shape shape in Shapes)
        {
            shape.Draw();
        }

        foreach (Shape shape in Shapes)
        {
            shape.Scale(Scale);
        }
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        foreach (Shape shape in Shapes)
        {
            shape.Clear();
        }
    }

    public static Picture FromXml(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Picture));
        return serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as Picture;
    }
}
```

And for example the input XML file will look like:

```
<Picture>
    <Scale>0.9</Scale>
    <Shapes>
        <Circle id="1">
            <Radius>1.5</Radius>
        </Circle>
        <Circle id="2">
            <Radius>3</Radius>
        </Circle>
        <Rectangle id="3">
            <Height>300</Height>
            <Width>300</Width>
        </Rectangle>
    </Shapes>
</Picture>
```

But model classes contain a logic (Draw(), Clear() and Scale() methods) and it seems that it breaks a single responsibility principle. And therefore we don't know does it make sense to split that logic into several classes or not?

If yes, then how? Because once we read the XML file, all objects are accessible only as Shape objects and therefore we will have to explicitly cast the object either before passing if to the handler class or inside that method, for example:

```
public abstract class Drawer
{
    public abstract void Draw(Shape shape);
}

public class CircleDrawer : Drawer
{
    public override void Draw(Shape shape)
    {
        Circle circle = shape as Circle;
        if (circle == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Passed object is not of type Circle");
        }
    }
}
```

If that issue is known, please just redirect me to that resource.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to do the casting i.e. `shape as Circle`. Because `Circle` _is_ a `Shape`, it's perfectly happy to treat it as a `Shape`, but since `Circle` overrides the `Draw` method, the overridden method is the one that gets called. Consider the following... https://dotnetfiddle.net/YQxhph

Comment: Change from : Draw(Shape shape) to : Draw(Circle shape)

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the model and business logic,
So the object that will be deserialized will contain only the properties. 
Then, in the factory or method that creates the business logic, insert it as a member of the circle (for example) business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to separate model and business logic I get the following code. Is it acceptable? As for me, it looks not flexible: we should not forget to extend the if statement if we add a new shape drawer.

```
public abstract class Drawer
{
    public abstract void Draw();
}

public class CircleDrawer : Drawer
{
    private readonly Circle _circle;

    public CircleDrawer(Circle circle)
    {
        _circle = circle;
    }

    public override void Draw() { }
}

public class RectangleDrawer : Drawer
{
    private readonly Rectangle _rectangle;

    public RectangleDrawer(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        _rectangle = rectangle;
    }

    public override void Draw() { }
}

public class Picture
{
    public double Scale { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayAttribute("Shapes")]
    public Collection<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }

    public void Setup()
    {
        List<Drawer> drawers = new List<Drawer>();
        foreach (Shape shape in Shapes)
        {
            if (shape is Circle)
            {
                drawers.Add(new CircleDrawer(shape as Circle));
            }
            else if (shape is Rectangle)
            {
                drawers.Add(new RectangleDrawer(shape as Rectangle));
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        foreach (Drawer drawer in drawers)
        {
            drawer.Draw();
        }
    }

    public static Picture FromXml(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Picture));
        return serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as Picture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question in this case would be, is it needed that the caller knows the concrete type or is everything mapped through the common base class?

In your example all implementations share a common abstract base class. If all users can happily work with this common behaviour you just push around all instances casted to the base type. Nevertheless as you already mentioned this tends to put more and more business logic into each concrete class. Depending on how much (or better less) this is, it is absolutely okay to let it there (this seems to be your current solution).

If this is getting more or quite complex it would be a good way to move this into its own class and/or methods. In that case you need some kind of dispatcher, that decides which takes care for the given object. I start to use a dictionary for these cases that works as a dispatcher and has the given type as key and an Action or Func as value like this:

```
var dispatcher = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Shape>>
{
    { typeof(Rectangle), DoSomethingWithRectangle },
    { typeof(Circle), DoSomethingWithCircle }
}

private void DoSomethingWithRectangle(Shape shape)
{
    var rectangle = (Rectangle)shape;
    Console.WriteLine($"Rectangle Height: {rectangle.Height} Width: {rectangle.Width}");
}

private void DoSomethingWithCircle(Shape shape)
{
    var circle = (Circle)shape;
    Console.WriteLine($"Circle Radius: {circle.Radius}");
}
```

This is just a trivial example. The dictionary should be live within a dispatcher where you have some methods to register different types and instead of methods you could also register types or instances of classes that could handle each specific instance type. If this kind of dispatching is still not matching all your cases you could maybe take a look at [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki) which formalized these things much more with a bunch of type-safe interfaces which you use to define your input types, the desired return value and an handler that is capable of doing this job.